# Error petición HTTP

Tags: spring, angular4

Que tal comunidad desarrollando mi aplicacion me basada en angular 4 + spring boot tengo error al realizar las peticiones HTTP por medio de angular.

El back de mi aplicacion funciona bien y envia el json cuando realizo peticiones sin embargo cuando las intento realizar por medio de angular me envia este error.

```
 Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8080/VL/internet: No 'Access-Control-Allow-
 Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

 core.js:1350 ERROR Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, 
 statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}
```

Segun he investigado eso pasa por hacer una peticion aun dominio diferente al de mi pagina de angular sin embargo no se entonces como resolver el problema para que no me de ese error y obtenga el json que envio desde el back hecho con spring boot

Aqui mi servicio de angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
@Injectable()
export class VentaLineaService {

  URL_INTERNET_20 : string = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/VL/internet";

  constructor( private http:Http) { }

  getInternet20 (){
    return this.http.get(this.URL_INTERNET_20).map( res => { 
         console.log(res)});
  }

}
```

Comment: la respuesta es de spring y tu pregunta fue de angular4 siu es valida la respuesta por favor modifica la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

Quizá debas añadir en tu BackEnd el **Cross Origin Requests** [En esto puedes basarte para la configuración de tu servicio](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

O prueba con **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"** al contenido de tus headers que al parecer no le estas añadiendo a esa petición

Comment: muchas gracias tienes razón me falto añadir en mi clase controller del backend la etiqueta @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") de spring